# Why doesn't 7-zip appear in the contextual menu in Windows Explorer for MATLAB's .mat files after installing MS Office?

Tags: 7-zip, matlab

I use MATLAB and after installing MS Office 7-zip doesn't appear any more in the contextual menu when trying to zip some .mat files: http://youtu.be/uJvSC4oCes8. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAT-files became associated with Microsoft Access during the MS Office installation, and are treated as shortcuts. Since you cannot compress shortcuts, you cannot compress .mat files anymore. The solution is to restore the file associations by following this tutorial: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-VW0R7/

[image]